mode-line-format: How to ensure `:eval`'d code is evaluated when necessary?
I'm trying to show full b/B bytes, l/L lines, c/C columns in the mode line (where n/N denotes "point is at n of N total), all zero-based, with both sides of each fraction padded as needed to keep their / at fixed places.
Since that doesn't seem to be feasible with built-in %-constructs (as of emacs 28.2), I've added three let* statements like this one to my mode-line-format:
(-13
 (:eval
  (let*
      ((inhibit-field-text-motion t)
       (line-number-at-accessible-buffer-beginning
        (line-number-at-pos (point-min)))
       (line-number-at-point
        (line-number-at-pos (point)))
       (line-number-at-accessible-buffer-end
        (line-number-at-pos (point-max)))
       (accessible-lines-count
        (- line-number-at-accessible-buffer-end line-number-at-accessible-buffer-beginning))
       (accessible-lines-count-length
        (length (number-to-string accessible-lines-count))))
    (format
     (concat "  %#"
         (number-to-string accessible-lines-count-length)
         "s/%sL")
     (number-to-string
      (- line-number-at-point line-number-at-accessible-buffer-beginning))
     (number-to-string accessible-lines-count)))))

This works as intended, except that if mode-line-format still includes mode-line-position, its own display of size, line and column numbers wastes over 20 chars of mode line estate for no extra information.
So, let's remove mode-line-postion and it's all fine?
Not quite.
As soon as mode-line-position isn't present somewhere in mode-line-format anymore (nor is %l), the code above becomes weirdly laggy. If you then move the point e. g. from line number 100 down to 105 through nothing but indentation space, it keeps displaying 100 unless the buffer has started scrolling. The lags vanish the moment mode-line-position (or %l) is added to mode-line-format again.
Apparently, these built-in constructs use some smart laziness that makes their output update reliably whenever the point's line number changes, and the let* statement then gets evaluated along.
(Everything said about lines and "%l"above also holds for columns and "%c"`, respectively.)
How can the :eval'd code be forced to be evaluated when necessary, or follow the smart evaluation policy employed by mode-line-position/"%l"/"%c" constructs without actually including them?

I would generally advise doing as little as possible in :eval code in the mode line.  The mode line can be refreshed very frequently, for each and every window.  I haven't tried to analyse your code, but it seems like a lot.  Any time you can use other mechanisms to update a variable only when required and in your mode line just display the variable value... do that.

And lastly, force-mode-line-update does what it says, but if you mean you're trying to use it within the :eval code, that's nonsensical.  Your :eval code is only ever being evaluated when the mode line is being updated -- it makes no sense at all to ask Emacs to update the mode line within that code, while it's already in the process of updating the mode line (and I'd expect it to explicitly ignores that request in order to avoid blowing the stack with endless recursion).

What @phils said - all of it.

@phils: I'd love to get this done by predefined constructs! Alas, everything I've tried before resorting to :eval has failed, because: 1. mode-line-format doesn't offer a zero-based %l-construct; 2. the (NUM FORM) directive only offers right-padding (whilst keeping the / in place requires left-padding); 3. it only allows an explicit integer NUM (whilst padding length needs to be calculated dynamically); 4. within (:eval (format ...)) (which solves 2. and 3.), mode-line's %-constructs don't behave well, so I use local variables instead (which also tackle 1.)

@Drew @phils Re force-mode-line-update: Thank you, makes sense! Despite hours of testing and reading docs, I was unaware that "evaluating mode-line-format" and "updating the mode line" are actually the same thing.

If I add "%l" and "%c" to mode-line-format, the :eval'd code is evaluated whenever the point moves, posing no performance issues, whatsoever. Without "%l"/"%c" though, it's rarely evaluated.
So the question remains: Is there any way to utilize %l's/%c's evaluation policies without actually including "%l"/"%c"? Or to specify custom triggers for :eval'd code, so it's evaluated e. g. "on every change of point"?

Indeed, the redisplay code does react to column changes when the format contains %c or %C: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/src/xdisp.c#L13594-L13602 -- the only way I can think of offhand to leverage that would be to propertize that string to have zero width.
